# Cambiar la contraseña en base de datos cuando se solicita una nueva

Tags: php, postgresql

Tengo un problema cuando se solicita una nueva contraseña por olvido u estravio, este es el codigo

```
$encriptar = password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "<script> alert('Mensaje no pudo ser enviado') </script>";
    echo "Error de envio " .$mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{

    $pg = "update usuarios set clave = '$encriptar' where correo_usuario = '$correo'";
    pg_query($pg);

    echo "<script> alert('Mensaje enviado') </script>";
}
```

El correo con la nueva contraseña llega bien, pero la clave no se cambia en la base de datos, ¿me falta algo o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: ¿Que te devuelve pg_query($pg)? Aparte, enviar las contraseñas por correo es un riesgo de seguridad.

Comment: podes asegurar que pg_query no esta devolviendo error?

Comment: Listo lo pude resolver, un tonto error con la conexion a la base de datos, y la contraseña que se envia por correo es una que se genera aleatoriamente para un unico uso, aun asi es peligrosa enviarla por correo?

Comment: @EdwinAquino Si el mensaje está cifrado no es peligroso.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu query por la siguiente:

```
//$pg = "update usuarios set clave = '$encriptar' where correo_usuario = '$correo'";
//pg_query($pg);
pg_query_params($conexion, 'UPDATE usuarios SET clave=$1 WHERE correo_usuario=$2;', [$encriptar, $correo]) or die(pg_last_error());
```

Porque no sabemos a que conexión estás afectando. De igual manera agrega un `or die()` a tu función de conexión con la base.